# AJAX call not returning values from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web

I am making an AJAX call but its not returning a value in the `success` handler. This is my AJAX call. I have checked that it's hitting the PHP file correctly

```
var msj;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxFile.php",
    data: {
        name: name,
        status: status,
        description: description,
        action: 1
    },
    sucess: function(data){
        msj = data;
        alert(data);
    }
});
alert(msj);
```

My PHP code is as follow:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']))
{
    if ($_POST['action'] == 1) 
    {
        $obj = new project($_POST['name'], $_POST['active'], $_POST['description']);
        $obj = testInput($obj);
        $check = validateName($obj->getName());
        if ($check == 1) 
        {
            echo $nameError;
        } 
        else 
        {
            print "asdasdasd";
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me tracking the mistake.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi why? The data returned from PHP is just a string

Comment: Can you include a `var_dump($_POST)` to the question?

Comment: Can you log `$_POST['action']` this in the top of the page?

Comment: Note that there is a typo: `sucess` should be `success`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes you are right.

Comment: You don't send `active` as part of the ajax data, so `$_POST['active']` is not set (another typo?). Also where is `$nameError` defined?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there's a syntax error in  your code. There's `sucess` instead of `success`.

Answer (score 0):

You are only providing a "success" callback function. You should also provide an "error" callback so you can debug and see what is wrong. You can also provide a "complete" callback that will be used in both alternatives.

```
var msj;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ajaxFile.php",
        data:{name:name,status:status,description:description,action:1},
        complete:function(data){
            msj=data;
            alert(data);
      }
    });
alert(msj);
```

In your PHP, you could add

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

to make sure JQuery identify well your web service.